# Doctrine Many To One Mapping Issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am getting the following error in my "Create Product" page when trying to create a foreign key mapping (i.e mapping Category to Product):

> A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type
>   "CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\Category" passed to the choice field. To
>   read a custom getter instead, set the option "property" to the desired
>   property path.

Comment: See please [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702037/how-do-you-define-the-getter-to-use-in-a-crud-form-besides-defining-tostring). I assume it may be useful for u.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to add a `__toString()` method to your Category entity. For example:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

The PHP magic-method `__toString()` is used to present a textual representation of the object. In this case, the Category name will be used when selecting a Category in a Form of a related entity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Whats the logic behind needing the function. Like I got an idea looking at the error but I didn't know what to do with it.

Comment: The answer didn't help me, I also wrote an answer immediately and was just commenting on your superior speed. :)

Answer (score 6):

The error message is telling you what you need to do. In your Category entity you need to add a __toString() method so that when you add a product it knows what to name each item in the select box on the form.

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

In the above replace 'name' with whichever field is the readable identifier for your category.