# How do you define the getter to use in a CRUD form besides defining __toString()?

Tags: symfony, scaffolding

If you've used Symfony2's generators to create CRUD forms from database entities, you may wind with an error like this on the "create new record" screen:

```
StringCastException: A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type
"ScrumBoard\ServiceBundle\Entity\Users" passed to the choice field. To read a
custom getter instead, set the option "property" to the desired property path.
```

If I'm reading this correctly, the problem is that it needs to display a dropdown list of users for the record I'm creating, but it doesn't know how to turn a "User" entity into a string.

Defining the __toString() method on my Users entity class fixes the problem.  However, I can see right from the text of the error message that there is an alternative: read a customer getter instead, which is accomplished by "[setting] the option "property" to the desired property path."

This sounds like some kind of annotation.  But in my searching, I can't figure out what that is.  Because I want to have a thorough understanding of Symfony2--can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Set it in the form builder call in your controller

Comment: Sorry, I just don't know what this means.  Do you have a link to the relevent documentation, or an example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When creating an entity ( superclass of choice ) field type in a form. You need to specify which property shall be used for the labels/values otherwise the __toString() method of the underlying object will be used.

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'property' => 'username',
));
```

Read more about it in the Form Type Reference for [entity field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property).

**Additional Info**

A __toString() related error generally often comes from twig when generating a route in a template aswell.
if outputting an object an object in twig with {{ object }} ... twig will call the object'S __toString method.
This "trick" is used by the crud generated templates with SensioGeneratorBundle.

```
 {{ path('article_show', {'id': article}) }}
```

with the route being something like this:

```
article_show:
   pattern:  /article/{id}
   defaults: { _controller: AcmeArticleBundle:Article:show }
```

If you have the __toString method in your Article entity set to something like ...

```
 public function __toString()
 {
     return $this->id;
 }
```

... you dont't need to type

```
{{ path('article_show', {'id': article.id) }}
```

Generally Twig will automatically output Article::getId() if you use

```
{{ article.id }}
```

Hope this clarifies your findings.